# How to loop over multiple values of a field with awk in bash?

Tags: bash, awk

My dataset looks like this:

```
lastname|name|hash
A|B|C
D|E|
G|H|I J
```

I need the data in this format (preferably with `awk`) in bash.

```
{C}% B A
{I}% H G
{J}% H G
```

In words: Only if there is a value for the third column (`hash`) I want to output.
There can be 1-n values in the third column (`hash`) and for each value the output should be like:

`{hash}% name lastname`

Comment: oh - thanks for pointing out. that was a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BEGIN { 
    FS="|"
}

NR>1 && NF==3 {
    split($3, a, " ")
    for (i=1;i in a;i++) printf("{%s}%% %s %s\n", a[i], $2, $1)
}
```

I think the above `awk` is self explanatory enough. To print the literal `%` with `printf` we have to escape it with `%%`. Testing:

```
> awk -f tst.awk file
{C}% B A
{I}% H G
{J}% H G
```

Comment: would it make any difference to use it directly as `awk`-command?

Comment: @LukasCB You would add `#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f` as shebang, save it as `tst` without the `.awk` extension. Make it execultable and run it with `./tst file`

Comment: @LukasCB - would it make any difference -- No, just more typing each time you want to run it...